# ForkJoinPool and parallel execution of queries

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, fork-join

I have several identical queries to the database that are executed with different parameters. I want to run them in parallel, and collect the result in a list. I read that I can use `ForkJoinPool` for this task, but I don't understand how to do it. And I want to limit the number of threads. As far as I understand, this can be done using `static final ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(count)`?

---

**Update** I got something like this

```
public class Updater {
    private PersonRepository personRepository;
    private static final ForkJoinPool FORK_JOIN_POOL = new ForkJoinPool(4);

    public Updater(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    public List<Person> updatePersons(List<Integer> ids) {
        return FORK_JOIN_POOL.submit(() -> {
            return ids.parallelStream()
                    .map(id -> personRepository.update(id))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of database? Got any code you've tried?

Comment: You want a task parallel framework, not a data parallel framework. Try this article and the open-source it references: http://www.coopsoft.com/ar/ForkJoinArticle.html

Comment: access to database is a blocking operation. Blocking operation are not recommended to be run by thread pool. Better run them on dedicated threads.

Comment: @Jason  database is MySql

Comment: @Alexei Kaigorodov I need to collect the result in a list.

Comment: @Violetta just create `list = new Arraylist()` and then call `list.add(item)` from each thread. ForkJoinPoll is not required.

Comment: When you have a problem, you should describe the problem, right in your question. Apparently, you forgot to call `join()` on the object returned by `submit`. Is that your problem? Do we really have to guess?